# Erro em animação jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    function moverFoto(){
         $('#janela').animate({left:"-200"},1000);
    }
    $( function(e) {
         setInterval(moverFoto,500);
    }); 
</script>
```

O setInterval só executa uma vez e para

Comment: nenhum erro no console

Comment: Do jeito que está o código vai mandar a **janela** para -200 e depois vai fazer isso novamente e novamente e daí por diante. Se você quer que ela vá cada vez 200 a menos você precisa pegar o valor atual e somar ao que quer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade o que você está fazendo é jogar o elemento pra left -200. Como na segunda vez ele já está nessa posição você não percebe a função executando novamente.

Um exemplo do código para que você perceba a função executando várias vezes é o seguinte:

```
var pLeft = parseInt($('#janela').css("left")); // Pega a posição atual do elemento em relação a esquerda da tela.

function moverFoto(){
  $('#janela').animate({left:pLeft},1000);
  pLeft -= 5; // A cada execução remove 5 pixels da posição atual
  console.log("Posição atual: " + pLeft); // Código que mostra no console a posição do elemento a cada looping
}

setInterval(moverFoto,500);
```

Entendendo o conceito, basta configurar a sua animação com os valores adequados.

Exemplo no JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9d62n48g/11/

Comment: vlw bro deu certo

Answer (score 2):

Não é que o `setInterval` só é executado 1 vez. É que quando você muda a posição do elemento para -200px com o `animate()`, na próxima vez que você chama-lo, ele não vai fazer nada porque o elemento já vai estar na posição -200px.

Você pode usar o callback do método para voltar o elemento para a posição inicial. Exemplo:

```js
function moverFoto(){
   $('#janela').animate({left:"0"},1000, function(){
      
      $(this).css("left", "500px");
      
   });
}
$( function(e) {
   setInterval(moverFoto,500);
});
```

```css
#janela{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   left: 500px;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="janela">janela</div>
```

Agora, o ideal mesmo seria usar `setTimeout` em vez de `setInterval`, porque o tempo do `setInterval` pode não ficar sincronizado com o tempo do `animate()`:

```js
function moverFoto(){
   $('#janela').animate({left:"10"},1000, function(){
      
      $(this).css("left", "500px");
      setTimeout(moverFoto,500);
   });
}
$( function(e) {
   setTimeout(moverFoto,500);
});
```

```css
#janela{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
   left: 500px;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="janela">janela</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você também pode usar o proprio css pra animação e colocar ela como **infinite** você só precisa chamar o função uma vez com **setTimeout**

```js
function moverFoto() {
  $("#janela").addClass("animar");
}

$(function(e) {
  setTimeout(moverFoto, 500);
});
```

```css
#janela {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.animar {
  animation: andar 2s infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes andar {
  0% {
    left: 0;
    opacity: 9;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 9;
  }
  100% {
    left: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="janela"></div>
```